# printing text in a column in bash script

Tags: bash, printf

I've been searching around and trying to find an answer, or even a question, similar to mine and have been unable to do so.  Perhaps someone here can help.

I'm trying to print a help text from my bash command. I want the command / option to be in one column and the explanation in the second column where if the text wraps, it starts on the correct column number.

I've tried `printf` and I don't quite understand the `column` commands.

Here is what I want:

```
myscript.sh         Execute without arguments to get a menu
                    of options defining the environment.
myscript.sh [url]   Add [url] to specify desired server
                    environment with which to run the script.
                    ex: http://the.server.domain.tld:port/
```

My attempt, thus far, looks like:

```
col1="%-15s"
col2="%15s\n"
printf "$col1" "myscript.sh"
printf "$col2" "Execute without arguments to get a menu of options defining the environment."
printf "$col1" "myscript.sh [url]"
printf "$col2" "Add [url] to specify desired server environment with which to run the script."
printf "$col2" "ex: http://the.server.domain.tld:port/"
```

but it ends up looking like

```
myscript.sh         Execute without arguments to get a menu
of options defining the environment.
myscript.sh [url]   Add [url] to specify desired server 
environment with which to run the script.
ex: http://the.server.domain.tld:port/
```

Comment: If you are wanting 2 columns with the first formatted, just use `col2="%s\n"` or for continuation lines in col2 you still must print a col1. e.g. before your last printf, add `printf "$col1" " "` In fact, you should probably combine your format into a single `col="%-15s%s"` and then provide both values to a single printf call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find it important to have the texts word-wrap automatically, taking into account the width of the terminal window, then you may want to use the following helper script; I named it `twocolumns.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
tabstop=$1
cols=$(tput cols)
paste <(echo "$2" | fold -sw$((tabstop-1))) <(echo "$3" | fold -sw$((cols-tabstop-1))) | expand -t$tabstop
```

Call it like this:

```
./twocolumns.sh 20 "myscript.sh" "Execute without arguments to get a menu of options defining the environment."
./twocolumns.sh 20 "myscript.sh [url]" "Add [url] to specify desired server environment with which to run the script."
./twocolumns.sh 20 "" "ex: http://the.server.domain.tld:port/"
```

Output in an 80-column terminal:

```
myscript.sh         Execute without arguments to get a menu of options 
                    defining the environment.
myscript.sh [url]   Add [url] to specify desired server environment with which 
                    to run the script.
                    ex: http://the.server.domain.tld:port/
```

Output in a 60-column terminal:

```
myscript.sh         Execute without arguments to get a 
                    menu of options defining the 
                    environment.
myscript.sh [url]   Add [url] to specify desired server 
                    environment with which to run the 
                    script.
                    ex: http://the.server.domain.tld:port/
```

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. I chose this as the best answer as it was concise and did exactly what I wanted. Instead of using a second script file, I put the code into a function.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a function that uses spaces to make everything fit.
The function with testdata:

```
function myprint {
   firstline=0    
   while read -r line; do
      if [[ "${firstline}" -eq 0 ]]; then
         header="$1"                     
         firstline=1                     
      else                               
         header=" "                      
      fi                                 
      printf "%-25s%s\n" "${header}" "${line}" 
   done <<< "$(fold -w30 -s <<< $2)"          
}                                              

h1="myscript.sh"
t1="Execute without arguments to get a menu of options defining the environment.  myscript.sh [url]   Add [url] to specify desired server environment with which to run the script.  ex: http://the.server.domain.tld:port/"  
h2="myscript.sh [url]"                                                                                         
t2="Add [url] to specify desired server environment with which to run the script.  ex: http://the.server.domain.tld:port/"                                                                                                    
myprint "$h1" "$t1"                                                                                            
myprint "$h2" "$t2"
```

Output:

```
    myscript.sh              Execute without arguments to
                             get a menu of options
                             defining the environment.
                             myscript.sh [url] Add [url]
                             to specify desired server
                             environment with which to run
                             the script. ex:
                             http://the.server.domain.tld:p
                             ort/
    myscript.sh [url]        Add [url] to specify desired
                             server environment with which
                             to run the script. ex:
                             http://the.server.domain.tld:p
                             ort/
```

Comment: This is a really neat function, thank you.  Unfortunately it doesn't work with colours, because fold reads the colour codes as extra characters...  I will post an answer here if I find an extended solution to this with colours working.

Comment: @JakeIreland I understand the problem, and don't know an easy fix. When you are interested in colours, you might like the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59866910/3220113 but that would not help here.

Answer (score 1):

When you are printing 1 formatted column and a following string, there is no need for 2 separate formats, simply provide both in a single format string:

```
#!/bin/bash

cols="%-20s%s\n"
printf "$cols" "myscript.sh" "Execute without arguments to get a menu of options."
printf "$cols" "myscript.sh [url]" "Add [url] to specify desired server."
printf "$cols" " " "ex: http://the.server.domain.tld:port/"
```

**note:** when using the *minimum* field width value, it is a **minimum** field width and the value you provide exceeds that width, it will print the whole string your provide.

Also, if you want to shift a continuation of column2 onto a second line, you still need to provided a value (either empty string or a space) for the column 1 value. If you look at the code above, the output would be:

**Output**

```
$ bash prncols.sh
myscript.sh         Execute without arguments to get a menu of options.
myscript.sh [url]   Add [url] to specify desired server.
                    ex: http://the.server.domain.tld:port/
```

(**note:** `myscript.sh [url]` is `17` characters and would exceed your format width of `15`, that is the reason `20` was used instead).

**Use a Heredoc Instead**

The proper way to provide formatted text such as *help* information is to use a *heredoc*, e.g.:

```
cat << EOF

    myscript.sh         Execute without arguments to get a menu of options.
    myscript.sh [url]   Add [url] to specify desired server.
                        ex: http://the.server.domain.tld:port/

EOF
```

Much easier to maintain and you have complete control over formatting between the heredoc *sigils*. (the example above indents the help information by 4 spaces).