# Keep text in place regardless output bash printf

Tags: linux, bash, shell, printf

This happens when numbers gets bigger...Just started with this mess.
Text being pushed around by bigger outputs...how do I contain this mess?

```
       Accounts......: 5      Mail..........: 7
       Banned........: 0      Pets..........: 1
       Online........: 0      Tickets.......: 0
       Guilds........: 1      Corpses.......: 0      PvP.......: 0
       Members.......: 1      Characters....: 10      Gifts.....: 4   <-----HOWTO Reserve/Preserve spaces ?? ??
```

Should look like this:

```
       Accounts......: 5      Mail..........: 7
       Banned........: 0      Pets..........: 1
       Online........: 0      Tickets.......: 0
       Guilds........: 1      Corpses.......: 0      PvP.......: 0
       Members.......: 1      Characters....: 10     Gifts.....: 4
```

Now this mess looks like this:

```
ch_count=$(mysql --defaults-extra-file="$sql_mycnf" -N --execute="SELECT count(*) FROM $db_characters.characters;"); &> /dev/null


cm_char="\033[0mCharacters\e[0;32m....:\033[0m $ch_count\e[31m"

line="      "

           $cm_acco$line$cm_mail
           $cm_bann$line$cm_pets
           $cm_onli$line$cm_tick
           $cm_guil$line$cm_corp$line$cm_pvps
           $cm_memb$line$cm_char$line$cm_gifts
```

On another server there is same outputs but because they are smaller it looks fine:

```
           Accounts......: 4      Mail..........: 0
           Banned........: 0      Pets..........: 0
           Online........: 0      Tickets.......: 0
           Guilds........: 0      Corpses.......: 0      PvP.......: 0
           Members.......: 0      Characters....: 2      Gifts.....: 0
```

Edit this line to make it work?
Is this correct place to begin?

```
cm_char="\033[0mCharacters\e[0;32m....:\033[0m $ch_count\e[31m"
```

Kill me.

Comment: You should format your numbers so they use the same amount of space. The code involved in getting your output is not shown, so cannot be of much more help. Just a pointer: take a look at `printf`.

Comment: Just check the length of each variable and adjust the spacing / $line variable accordingly

Comment: Just updated those lines with printf and where it get it from, rest looks the same.

Comment: " / $line variable accordingly " but they do get bigger... edit every time?

Comment: determine what the max numbers could be; this gives you the max width for that part of the output; modify your output command to take the 'extra' widths into consideration (eg, adjust a`printf` format from '%1s` to '%3s' to go from a 1-digit to a 3-digit number)

Comment: Still being pushed around.

Comment: " format your numbers so they use the same amount of space. " Not sure what this means.

Comment: " printf format from '%1s` to '%3s' " 

Where do I use %1s ? Not even inside the script and I adjust it with %3s ?

Where? It gives me spaces putting it inside printf , where can I reserve spaces?
All I have seen is me getting more spaces and pushes it even more.

Very frustrating.

Comment: Googling gives me so many different solutions you just want to scrap everything.

Comment: Your problem is because `Characters....: 10` needs to be `Characters...: 10` (where one dot has been removed) OR you need to redesign your layout so that all values positions (`10` in this case) are designed to accept a value that is more than one digit wide. If you require such perfect formatting, you'll need to allow for the largest possible number for every element of your report, right? So if you design for 2 max digits, any 1 digit value will have a space between the `:` and the number AND you'll have to remove a `.` char to make up for the space you have added, Good luck!

Comment: Values will go up to three spaces 999 at least maybe even more.. should be something that tells it is reserved.

editing script every time a bigger number arrives is just hilariously crazy.

Comment: edit script so it looks nice on one server - another server is now wrong.

so removing dots solution is just lazy and crazy.

Comment: The script: https://github.com/Daedalus-code/cmangos-script

Line 190 ---> 261

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make 2 functions that will format the fields and use them:

```
dot_field() {
   # todo Change implementation when field can be 2 words with a space in between
   printf "%-14.14s:" "$1" | tr ' ' '.'
}

space_number() {
   printf "%-7.7s" "$1"
}

printline() {
   # Todo: add logic when only 4 parameters are given
   echo "       $(dot_field $1) $(space_number $2)$(dot_field $3) $(space_number $4)$(dot_field $5) $(space_number $6)"
}

printline "Guilds" 1 "Corpses" 0 "PvP" 0
printline "Members" 1 "Characters" 10 "Gifts" 4
printline "LongFieldName" 1 "High" 999999 "X" 2
```

EDIT: Adding colors.

You don't want to have your code full of escape codes for the colors. It depends on the full context how you would like to structure your color codes, I give an example for the limited context of the question. It should give you an idea how you can make something like this for yourself.

```
init_colors() {
    reset=$(tput sgr0)
    bold=$(tput bold)
    black=$(tput setaf 0)
    red=$(tput setaf 1)
    green=$(tput setaf 2)
    yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
    blue=$(tput setaf 4)
    magenta=$(tput setaf 5)
    cyan=$(tput setaf 6)
    white=$(tput setaf 7)
    user_color=$bold
}

# colorstring reads from stdin and uses parameter 1 as an escape sequence
# with more parameters the first is used as a color, the other as the string to be modified
# It will set colors until the last space sequence
colorstring() {
   case $# in
   0) # invalid
      echo "colorstring called without parameters"
   ;;
   1)
      sed -r "s/^.*[^ ]/$1&${reset}/"
      ;;
   *)
      color="$1"
      shift
      sed -r "s/^.*[^ ]/${color}&${reset}/" <<< "$@"
   ;;
   esac

}

dot_field() {
   # todo Change implementation when field can be 2 words with a space in between
   printf "%-14.14s" "$1" | colorstring ${cyan} | tr ' ' '.'
   # The : must be printed in a second statement when you don't want cyan dots.
   printf ':'
}

space_number() {
   printf "%-7.7s" "$1" | colorstring ${red}
}

printline() {
   echo "       $(dot_field $1) $(space_number $2)$(dot_field $3) $(space_number $4)$(dot_field $5) $(space_number $6)"
}

# init the color variables
init_colors
# Next echo not needed, just testing the new colorstring function
echo "$(colorstring ${blue} blue string) $(colorstring ${red} red car) $(colorstring ${white} white snow) $(colorstring ${yellow} yellow marker) $(colorstring ${cyan} cyan) "
printline "Guilds" 1 "Corpses" 0 "PvP" 0
printline "Members" 1 "Characters" 10 "Gifts" 4
printline "LongFieldName" 1 "High" 999999 "X" 2
```

Comment: Thank you Walter A ! so simple and I got room to play with now.

Comment: How do you add color and where?
At numbers and dots.

Comment: I could make new $ with colors like last time. (so many lines tho)

Comment: @Antarctica colors added.

Answer (score 2):

As you may alredy know there are some spesial system sequinces
that controll output to terminal. This for example will turn text red '\e[31m'
and this will print text in certain column\line '\e[${LINE};${COLUMN}H'.
So we will use that. First i will create this 'data' array with "name value" pairs
to simulate your case.

```
data=(
    "Accounts   5"
    "Banned     10"
    "Online     40"
    "Guilds     4"
    "Members    1"
    "Mail       71"
    "Pets       43"
    "Tickets    0"
    "Corpses    101"
    "Characters 10"
    "PvP        0"
    "Gifts      4"
)
```

I'm using this [table](https://github.com/vaniacer/bash_color) when working with text output so lets used it to

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------+
#Color picker, usage: printf ${BLD}${CUR}${RED}${BBLU}"Hello!)"${DEF}|
#-------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+
#       Text color        |       Background color         |         |
#-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------------+         |
# Base color|Lighter shade|  Base color  | Lighter shade   |         |
#-----------+-------------+--------------+-----------------+         |
BLK='\e[30m'; blk='\e[90m'; BBLK='\e[40m'; bblk='\e[100m' #| Black   |
RED='\e[31m'; red='\e[91m'; BRED='\e[41m'; bred='\e[101m' #| Red     |
GRN='\e[32m'; grn='\e[92m'; BGRN='\e[42m'; bgrn='\e[102m' #| Green   |
YLW='\e[33m'; ylw='\e[93m'; BYLW='\e[43m'; bylw='\e[103m' #| Yellow  |
BLU='\e[34m'; blu='\e[94m'; BBLU='\e[44m'; bblu='\e[104m' #| Blue    |
MGN='\e[35m'; mgn='\e[95m'; BMGN='\e[45m'; bmgn='\e[105m' #| Magenta |
CYN='\e[36m'; cyn='\e[96m'; BCYN='\e[46m'; bcyn='\e[106m' #| Cyan    |
WHT='\e[37m'; wht='\e[97m'; BWHT='\e[47m'; bwht='\e[107m' #| White   |
#----------------------------------------------------------+---------+
# Effects                                                            |
#--------------------------------------------------------------------+
DEF='\e[0m'   #Default color and effects                             |
BLD='\e[1m'   #Bold\brighter                                         |
DIM='\e[2m'   #Dim\darker                                            |
CUR='\e[3m'   #Italic font                                           |
UND='\e[4m'   #Underline                                             |
INV='\e[7m'   #Inverted                                              |
COF='\e[?25l' #Cursor Off                                            |
CON='\e[?25h' #Cursor On                                             |
#--------------------------------------------------------------------+
# Text positioning, usage: XY 10 10 "Hello World!"                   |
XY   () { printf "\e[${2};${1}H${3}"; } #                            |
#--------------------------------------------------------------------+
# Print line, usage: line - 10 | line -= 20 | line "Hello World!" 20 |
line () { printf -v LINE "%$2s"; printf -- "${LINE// /$1}"; } #      |
# Create sequence like {0..X}                                        |
cnt () { printf -v _N %$1s; _N=(${_N// / 1}); printf "${!_N[*]}"; } #|
#--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

There are all basic colors set as vars to easily insert in text and some
usefull functions like XY i'll use it to print text in serrtain position.

Lets set some vars

```
space_betwen=7  # space betwen columns
X=$space_betwen # starting X(column) position
Y=10            # starting Y(line) position

dot_string='...............: ' # dot string to simulate your output
dot_length=${#dot_string}      # this will calculate the length of the dot string
```

Ok we are ready to go but first lets clear all text from terminal screen

```
clear
```

And now we can iterate through data and print text in 3 columns by 4 lines

```
for item in "${data[@]}"; {
    ((counter++)) # lets count items to know when start next column
    read name value <<< $item # get naame and value from current item
    XY $X $Y "$dot_string$RED$value$DEF" # print dot string and red value
    XY $X $Y "$YLW$name$DEF" # name will be printed ower dots in yelow color
    ((Y++)) # go to next line by increasing Y value
    # chek if we print 4 lines than set Y to start poosition and inc X to space_betwen+dot_length
    ((counter%4)) || { Y=10; ((X+=space_betwen+dot_length)); }
}
```

The final script will be like this

```
    #!/bin/bash

    data=(
        "Accounts   5"
        "Banned     10"
        "Online     40"
        "Guilds     4"
        "Members    1"
        "Mail       71"
        "Pets       43"
        "Tickets    0"
        "Corpses    101"
        "Characters 10"
        "PvP        0"
        "Gifts      4"
    )

    . ~/SCR/color   # include color table
    space_betwen=7  # space betwen columns
    X=$space_betwen # starting X(column) position
    Y=10            # starting Y(line) position

    dot_string='...............: ' # dot string to simulate your output
    dot_length=${#dot_string}      # this will calculate the length of the dot string

clear

for item in "${data[@]}"; {
    ((counter++)) # lets count items to know when start next column
    read name value <<< $item # get naame and value from current item
    XY $X $Y "$dot_string$RED$value$DEF" # print dot string and red value
    XY $X $Y "$YLW$name$DEF" # name will be printed ower dots in yelow color
    ((Y++)) # go to next line by increasing Y value
    # chek if we print 4 lines than set Y to start poosition and inc X to space_betwen+dot_length
    ((counter%4)) || { Y=10; ((X+=space_betwen+dot_length)); }
}
XY 1 20 "$DEF" # one more time to move cursor down in the end
```

And the output will be like this
[image: output example]

Comment: I get XY: command not found on another linux with Ubuntu server also.
It works on terminal on MacBook

Comment: @Antarctica, Glad to help) XY it's not a command it's a function that i've made. It's from 'color table'. There it is `XY () { printf "\e[${2};${1}H${3}"; }`