# How to set a variable with color and left align with bash

Tags: bash, printf, tput, leftalign

How do I set a variable with color and left align with bash

Example:

```sh
red=$(tput setaf 1)
green=$(tput setaf 2)
normal=$(tput sgr0)


if [ $process_state != "running" ]; then
    process_state=${red}$process_state${normal}
else
    process_state=${green}$process_state${normal}
fi

printf "%-10s|" $process_state
```

Inputs

```sh
process_state=running
process_state=stopped
```

Output

```sh
running   | <-- Where this is in green
stopped   | <-- Where this is in red
```

*** UPDATED *** Solution:

```sh
red=$(tput setaf 1)
green=$(tput setaf 2)
normal=$(tput sgr0)


if [ $process_state != "running" ]; then
    process_state="${red} $process_state ${normal}"
else
    process_state="${green} $process_state ${normal}"
fi

printf "%s%-10s%s|" $process_state
```

Note: Notice the spaces around $process_state separating it from color.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/59866910/3220113 help?

Comment: You should add your own solution as a separate answer instead of putting it into the question, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be a problem with the computation of the width of the field in the way you are doing it because `$red` and `$green` do not have a zero width for printf.

I would recode in the next way:

```
red=$(tput setaf 1)
green=$(tput setaf 2)
normal=$(tput sgr0)

if [ "$process_state" != "running" ]; then
    printf "%s%-10s%s|" "$red" "$process_state" "$normal"
else
    printf "%s%-10s%s|" "$green" "$process_state" "$normal"
fi
```

Comment: Suggestion for improvement: add quotes around `$process_state` in the `if` statement in case `process_state` is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added the solution of what I was looking for in the question.